# Test classes visibility

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

I have a project A that contains the data model code (Hibernate) and some unit tests. I also have other projects B, C and D with their code and unit tests. I also have a set of test utilities classes used by the unit tests of all the projects. These test utilities classes depend on project A because they use the data model classes.

If I put these test utilities classes in the project A, I get the following problem: how projects B, C and D may view these test utilities classes outside the IDE (I precise that these test utilities classes are placed in the src/test/java directory and then are not included in the JAR)?

If I put these test utilities classes in a separated project, I get a circular dependency because the test utilities classes depend on project A and the unit tests of A use these test utilities classes.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These test utilities classes should be packaged (by your build process) in a separate JAR file that the other projects use only when running tests.

Comment: See my comment to Manish Sharma, please.

Comment: @Mickael Marrache: We're not saying you should put the test utilities in a separate project, we're saying you should have one project A from which two JARs are built, one containing the test utilities and one containing the production code.

Comment: Good point but it seems that it's not recommended by Maven: see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html , so I thought there was a cleaner solution.

Comment: @Mickael Marrache: If by "project" you mean "Maven POM", then the "clean" solution is to have *three* projects, one (A1) with the production classes, one (A2) with the test utilities that depends on A1, and one (A3) with the tests, which depends on A1 and A2

Comment: I understand but it seems strange to put production classes and unit tests on two separated projects, that's a scenario I never seen. Generally, the unit tests are put in the src/test/java directory of the same project where production classes are. Why am I getting this "special" situation? Maybe a bad design on the unit tests or test utilities classes?

Comment: @Mickael Marrache: The problem seems to me to lie mainly with Maven's rigid concept of "one project == one release artifact", which forces projects to be subdivided. Maybe someone who knows Maven better can think of a better solution - it's really a Maven question more than one about your design.

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle each project in its own jar - A.jar, B.jar, C.jar, D.jar and put the utilities classes in their own jar - testutilities.jar

Then you can easily include the testutilities in other projects by including the testutilities.jar. You will also need to include A.jar as testutilities.jar depend on A.jar.

Comment: The problem is that the Test Utilities classes depend on project A, and the unit tests of A use these utilities classes. So, if I put the Test Utilities classes on a separated project, I get a circular dependency.